# How to provide deduction guide for nested template class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

According to [[temp.deduct.guide/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.guide#3)]:

> (...) A deduction-guide shall be declared in the same scope as the
>   corresponding class template and, for a member class template, with
>   the same access. (...)

But below example doesn't seem to compile in both [[gcc]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1rdB8ARfgFgqr8te) and [[clang]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8Q2p6eZLxTkU2WR1).

```
#include <string>

template <class>
struct Foo {
    template <class T>
    struct Bar {
        Bar(T) { }
    };
    Bar(char const*) -> Bar<std::string>;
};

int main() {
    Foo<int>::Bar bar("abc");
    static_cast<void>(bar);
}
```

What is the correct syntax of deduction guide for nested template class? Or maybe this one is correct but it isn't yet supported by the compilers?

---

Similar syntax but without nested class compiles fine both in gcc and clang:

```
#include <string>

template <class T>
struct Bar {
    Bar(T) { }
};
Bar(char const*) -> Bar<std::string>;

int main() {
    Bar bar("abc");
    static_cast<void>(bar);
}
```

Comment: In GCC it's a bug, in that it think you declare a function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not sure if it is a correct syntax though - there is no corresponding example in the standard yet it mentions the situation...

Comment: The nested template deduction guide works if the parent class is not templated....

Comment: @AndyG yep the syntax seems to be correct

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[[temp.deduct.guide]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.guide#3.sentence-4) includes the sentence:

> A *deduction-guide* shall be declared in the same scope as the corresponding class template and, for a member class template, with the same access.

This suggests that your example should work - deduction guides are explicitly supported for member class templates, as long as they're declared in the same scope and access (which would be the class scope and `public` - check and check).

This is [gcc bug 79501](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79501) (filed by Richard Smith).

Comment: @W.F. Your outer class is a class template, the example in this bug is simpler. Should file an llvm bug.

Comment: Yep this definitely suggests that the syntax should be correct. I'll try to file a bug then...

Comment: Just filed [llvm bug 34520](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34520)

Comment: According to Richard, this is a defect. See comment #1 on [PR35107](https://llvm.org/pr35107).

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* need a **temporary quick-fix**, consider using compiler-specific instructions.

[Here, on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/qM5MzTYhf)

The key is to handle the behavioral divergence between GCC and Clang by adding a compiler-specific directive.
This is way **sub-optimal**, but if you are blocked in your project, it may help you wait for compiler(s) patch.

See my answer to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66888013/10883423

```cpp
#include <string>

template <class>
struct Foo {
    template <class T>
    struct Bar {
        Bar(T) { }
    };
    #if __clang__
    Bar(char const*) -> Bar<std::string>;
    #endif
};

void instanciate_symbols()
{
    [[maybe_unused]] auto bar = Foo<int>::Bar{"abc"};
}
```