# Deduction guides, templates and subobjects: which compiler is right?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following snippet:

```
struct S {
    S() {}

    template<typename B>
    struct T {
        T(B &&) {}
    };

    template<typename B>
    T(B &&) -> T<B>;
};

int main() {
    S::T t{0};
}
```

Clang [accepts it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Dgkltwsz4Px2foxA) while GCC [rejects the code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/q4mI8tP4FYmiYiJC) with the following error:

> prog.cc:10:5: error: deduction guide 'S::T(B&&) -> S::T' must be declared at namespace scope

Is this valid code? Which compiler is right, GCC or Clang?

Comment: A little [bit more complex example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103102/how-to-provide-deduction-guide-for-nested-template-class) seem to still fail in both gcc and clang so don't be overoptimistic with clang ability to compile nested deduction-guides :)

Comment: @W.F. Apparently CTAD doesn't work for classes inside template classes; standard defect (see my comment on the linked answer).

Comment: now fixed in GCC 12 (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79501)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

> User-defined deduction guides must name a class template and must be introduced within the same semantic scope of the class template (which could be namespace or enclosing class) and, for a member class template, must have the same access, but deduction guides do not become members of that scope.

So clang seems correct.

Comment: I saw it, but I failed to find something along this line in the standard. Can you help on this?

Comment: @skypjack from [\[temp.deduct.guide\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.guide#3) : "A deduction-guide shall inhabit the scope to which the corresponding class template belongs and, for a member class template, have the same access."