# C++17 Deduction Guide defined inside a class is not effective inside this class, but useful outside the class

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction, deduction-guide

```
#include <variant>

struct A { };

struct B { };

struct Test
{
    template<typename Ts>
    struct overloaded : Ts { };

    // 1st Deduction Guide
    template<typename Ts>
    overloaded(Ts)->overloaded<Ts>;

    // 2nd Deduction Guide for class "A"
    overloaded(A)->overloaded<A>;

    void Fun()
    {
        // OK
        overloaded obj1{ A{} };

        // Error: No instance of constructor matches the argument list
        // I think the 1st Deduction Guide is not effective inside class "Test"
        overloaded obj2{ B{} };
    }
};

int main()
{
    // All Deduction Guides in class "Test" are effective here

    // OK
    Test::overloaded obj1{ A{} };

    // OK
    Test::overloaded obj2{ B{} };

    return 0;
}
```

I defined some `C++17` Deduction Guides inside a class called `Test`.

But I found that the 1st Deduction Guide, which includes a template argument `Ts` is not effective inside class `Test` itself. But effective outside it, such as in `main` function.

```
template<typename Ts>
overloaded(Ts)->overloaded<Ts>;
```

The 2nd Deduction Guide which does not include a template argument is effective both inside and outside the class.

```
overloaded(A)->overloaded<A>;
```

Can anyone tell me why?

My IDE is `Visual Studio 2019`, the C++ standard is `C++17`.

Thank you.

Comment: Accepted by clang, probably a bug in msvc.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/51hTG6

Comment: I get compile errors with `g++ -std=c++17`: deduction guide ‘Test::overloaded(Ts) -> Test::overloaded<Ts>’ must be declared at namespace scope

Comment: This question seems very related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50600645/deduction-guides-templates-and-subobjects-which-compiler-is-right

Comment: From the answer it seems that it's a bug in both `gcc` and `msvc`. Given @parktomatomi's comment, perhaps you could provide some more details about your Visual Studio version? x86 or x64? and the exact number of the version?

Comment: @Elliott  Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 Preview 3.2 or 4.0; x86; The C++ standard is `C++17`.